# Disable popup blocker in firefox

Tags: popup-blocker

From one of our application, we are calling window.open() method to open a pop up. When we are using this, the browsers are blocking the popup and user has to disable popup blocker for the specified web site.

Is there any way to disable the popup blockers for specified URL patterns(With out user intervention),like using browser API etc...

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to alter the browser's popup blocker behaviour from within a webpage. The best you can do is include a message on your website asking people to turn off their popup blockers while using your site so that the site can function properly.

Comment: In the kayak.com web site, they are opening multiple windows when we compare the flight prices. Here, the popup blocker is not blocking the windows. That is why, I am checking, is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Kayak is most likely doing it by having established itself as a trusted website, and gaining an exemption in the popup blocker. Or they're using a different method than you are. But the answer to your question remains, there is no way to alter the behaviour of a user's popup blocker from the code of your website.

Comment: I tried changing Mozilla config parameters dom.disable_open_during_load= true to false. It is working fine. But, I am searching for extension API to set this parameter.

Comment: What you are looking for DOES NOT EXIST. Being able to alter browser settings through javascript would be a HUGE security hole. Have you tried, I don't know, not relying on popup windows, which the average user finds incredibly annoying?